# DocuSign Signing Group in Demo Account?

Tags: docusignapi, demo

We have a DocuSign REST API application which creates and sends Envelopes to users. Everything works fine except that we need to have any of a group of users Counter Sign documents after end users have signed. We have a fairly high priced Enterprise account as well as Demo (https://appdemo.docusign.com/ ) account.

In the Demo account we do see something like 'XXX Corp. (already a customer)'. But, unlike the Enterprise account, we don't see any option to create a Signing Groups.

Can someone confirm that's the case for the Demo account, even for the paying customers? We are hesitant to promote our applications to production because we want to fully test in the Demo account. **Hello DocuSign!!**

Any other options to allow any of a group's members to counter sign so that the member's own name and signature are affixed on the document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocuSign Demo environment accounts *should* have full functionality, but in some cases they don't. Open a case with [DocuSign Support](http://support.docusign.com/) requesting Signing Groups be enabled on that account and that can be added.

In the case, be sure to include the account id and specifiy that this is in demo.

Comment: Thanks Drew. I just opened a Support Ticket with Docu Sign. Fingers crossed.

Comment: Yes! Docu Sign 'Resolved' my Case promptly by enabling the Signing Group. Thank you all for help here!

Answer (score 1):

DocuSign demo account should have all the capabilities that DocuSign offers.

From [Documentation](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#create-sandbox)

> Developer sandboxes are free, they don't expire, and they have enterprise level features enabled. Documents sent in the demo environment are not legally binding and have testing watermarks on them.

---

The signing groups in your production account will not be readily available in the Demo account. You will have to create new signing groups in the Demo account. See documentation [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-signing-groups)

Comment: Thanks. I am logged in as an Admin in the Demo but still don't see any option on the left panel for Signing Group--and that's the problem. Can you confirm it if you have a Demo account?